# Update data from Bootstrap Modal and load data without closing the modal

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a webpage, how do i update some data from a Bootstrap Modal into the SQL database using AJAX. I already done updating it with PHP and SQL Query. I'm totally new to AJAX,
I want to update data from text-area in a modal and the data should appear in the modal after submitting to database, and the modal should not close after submit/save. I've been struck with this for two days. 
Any Help please. Thanks in Advance.

enter image description here

[Button to Trigger Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QbEA.png)

[Comments Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWn5w.png)

[Update.Php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J96CK.png)

My code looks like this now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var comment;
$('#saveComments').on("click", function(){
    comment = $('#commentsModal').val();
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'update.php',
    data: { commentsModal: comment },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        /* $("#success-alert").show();
            setTimeout(function() { $("#success-alert").hide(); }, 5000); */
    },
});
```

});

And Php Code:

```
<?php
```

include "connect.php";

```
    $comments = $_POST['commentsModal']; 

    $commentQuery = "UPDATE new_project SET Comments = CONCAT(new_project.Comments, '<br>', '$comments', '<br>', '$date') WHERE new_project.ID = $id";

    mysql_query($commentQuery);
        if($conn->query($commentQuery) === TRUE){
            echo 'Added' ;
        }else{
            echo "Error:" . $commentQuery . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        } 

    $conn->close();
```

?>

Comment: Post your code so we can help you and track your errors. Without code it's difficult to help because nobody knows where you're standing right now.

Comment: Hello Jonas! I've attached pictures of the code. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for your help. I found out a way for my issue. I changed my whole table into Editable Table using `contenteditable="true"` and it works. Using `contenteditable` you can post your data from webpage to database without reloading the page. And I'm showing my whole table inside a modal, It works perfect.

> index.php

```
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="fixed-column"><strong> Issues </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Test Object </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> HW and SW Delivery Issues </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Status at Previous MRD </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Recommendation Previous CRB </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Functional Implementation on Status </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Issues for Upcoming Activities </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> System Verification Status </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Next Check Point </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Last Updated </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Comments </strong></th>
        <th class="text-align"><strong> Action Point </strong></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['Issues']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'Issues', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['Issues']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['testObject']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'testObject', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['testObject']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['deliveryIssues']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'deliveryIssues', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['deliveryIssues']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['prevMRD']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'prevMRD', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['prevMRD']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['prevCRB']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'prevCRB', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['prevCRB']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['Func_Imple']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'Func_Imple', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['Func_Imple']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['upcomingIssues']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'upcomingIssues', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['upcomingIssues']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['statusVerify']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'statusVerify', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['statusVerify']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['nextChkPoint']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'nextChkPoint', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['nextChkPoint']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['lastUpdated']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'lastUpdated', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['lastUpdated']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['Comments']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'Comments', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['Comments']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-align" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $item['actionPoint']; ?>" onBlur="saveInLineEdit(this, 'actionPoint', '<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $item['actionPoint']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

> function.js

```
function highlightEdit(editableObj) {
  $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
}

function saveInLineEdit(editableObj,column,id) {
   // no change change made then return false
   if($(editableObj).attr('data-old_value') === editableObj.innerHTML)
   return false;
   // send ajax to update value
   $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
   $.ajax({
      url: "saveInlineEdit.php",
      cache: false,
      data:'column='+column+'&value='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
      success: function(response)  {
         console.log(response);
         // set updated value as old value
         $(editableObj).attr('data-old_value',editableObj.innerHTML);
         $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");            
    }          
  });
}
```

> update.php

```
<?php
  include "connect.php";

  $sql = "UPDATE new_project SET ".$_REQUEST["column"]." = '".$_REQUEST["value"]."' WHERE id= $id ";

  mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook at submit event and run your custom js code, eg.

```js
$('form#update').submit(function(){
  $.post('add.php', $(this).serialize(), function(resultData){
    //resultData - data from you php script.

  })
  return false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You catch the click on the button

   ```
   $("#saveComments").on("click, function({
   ```
2. You get the value of the textarea

   ```
   comment = $("#commentsModal").val();
   ```
3. You send it through AJAX to your php

   ```
    $.ajax({

    url: 'update.php',

    data: {
     commentsModal: comment
    }
    success: function(data) {

    },
    type: 'POST'
    });
   ```
4. In the success-part of the above ajax-function you could add your comment to a div or wherever you want to have him.

Comment: Hello Jonas, Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it doesn't do anything. Do i need to make any changes in the SQL part?

Comment: Show your code how it is now (not as picture, please).
And debug, try to find out if the data gets to update.php by printing out your $_POST-array. And check for the request and response in the console of your browser.